# Jenkins using docker as an agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

I am not able to integrate Docker with Jenkins completely. I setup Docker at Cloud Node settings in the Jenkins portal. How can I use some image that contains Node, Ruby, etc? Must those images contain a JDK?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great post with a detailed explanation of how to deal with this [here](https://medium.com/@narenchejara/how-to-configure-docker-container-as-build-slaves-for-jenkins-d7795f78402d). In the post, they state that every Docker image (even if you require building a Node or Ruby project) requires a JDK. Seems the JDK requirement comes from the [Docker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/).